# Why would cortex-m3 reset to address 0 in gdb?

Tags: gdb, cortex-m, openocd

I am building a cross-compile toolchain for the Stellaris LM3S8962 cortex-m3 chip.  The test c++ application I have written will execute for some time then fault.  The fault will occur when I try to access a memory-mapped hardware device.  At the moment my working hypothesis is that I am missing some essential chip initialization in my startup sequence.

What I would like to understand is why would the execution in gdb get halted and the program counter be set to 0?  I have the vector table at 0x0, but the first value is the stack pointer.  Shouldn't I end up in one of the fault handlers I specify in the vector table?

```
(gdb) 
187     UARTSend((unsigned char *)secret, 2);
(gdb) cont

Continuing.

lm3s.cpu -- clearing lockup after double fault


Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00000000 in g_pfnVectors ()

(gdb) info registers 
r0             0x1      1
r1             0x32     50
r2             0xffffffff       4294967295
r3             0x0      0
r4             0x74518808       1951500296
r5             0xc24c0551       3259762001
r6             0x42052dac       1107635628
r7             0x20007230       536900144
r8             0xf85444a9       4166272169
r9             0xc450591b       3293600027
r10            0xd8812546       3632342342
r11            0xb8420815       3091335189
r12            0x3      3
sp             0x200071f0       0x200071f0
lr             0xfffffff1       4294967281
pc             0x1      0x1 <g_pfnVectors+1>
fps            0x0      0
cpsr           0x60000023       1610612771
```

The toolchain is based on gcc, gdb, openocd.

Comment: not sure about the pc being a zero|1 but look at that link register, that is very interesting.  I am a bit rusty on my thumb2, normal ARM with arm instructions boot up would go through and initialize all the stack pointers, well did you initialize your stack pointers or does that stack pointer imply system/user mode?  you might try changing all of the link registers. or if you can read the psr from gdb read that and find out what mode you are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDB happily gave you some clue:

> clearing lockup after double fault

Your CPU was in **locked** state. That means it could not run its "Hard Fault" Interrupt Handler (maybe there is a 0 in its Vector).

I usually get these when I forgot to "power" the periperial, the resulting Bus Error escalates first to "Hard Fault" and then to locked state. Should be mentioned in the manual of your MCU, btw.

Comment: It has been some time since I asked this question but I think you are right.  I seem to remember the root cause was a bus fault because I hadn't initialized the UART.  Good on you for taking the time to add the information on the public record.